# PHP SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from xsd

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, xsd

I am running some web services which are written using soap.

Some of the web services are running however those that try to import a local xsd are failing

```
<faultcode>WSDL</faultcode>
<faultstring>
    SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from 'http://localhost/myproject/_xsd/1'
</faultstring>
```

The following is an extract from my wsdl

```
<definitions
        xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
        xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy"
        xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
        xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata"
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
        xmlns:tns="http://ws.platform.commersite.com/"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
        targetNamespace="http://ws.platform.commersite.com/"
        name="PlatformControllerWSService">
<types>
    <xsd:schema>
        <xsd:import
                namespace="http://mysite/"
                schemaLocation="http://localhost/myproject/1" />
    </xsd:schema>
    <xsd:schema>
        <xsd:import
                namespace="http://somesite/"
                schemaLocation="http://localhost/myproject/_xsd/2" />
    </xsd:schema>
</types>
```

Loading the xsd files goes to a php function

```
public function _xsdAction($xsd) {
        $this->response->setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");

        $this->view->pick('server/_xsd' . $xsd);

        $this->view->setVars(array(
            'param1' => Server::config('param1'),
            'param2'  => Server::config('param2'),
        ));
}
```

Also worth mentioning is that xsd1 imports xsd2

```
<xs:import namespace="{{ param1 }}" schemaLocation="{{ param2 }}xsd/2"/>
```

I am not sure what the issue might be. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!

The problem was the path being used to locate the xsd file was incorrect as it was already entering the /myproject/ folder and did not require me adding the location of /myproject/ manually.